# Get string in bracket, with possible sub-brackets

Tags: python, string-formatting

I am making a script to parse and format the song title and artist for a radio station. The playout system will send track metadata to a python script

```
$ python metadata.py "title" "artist"
```

which will later send the formatted metadata to HTTP endpoints.

Metadata will come in this format;

```
Title: "Song Name (feat. ABC) (Ost. XYZ (aka. ASDF))"
Artist: "DEF"
```

As you can see, sometimes the `feat.` or `Ost.` can have sub-brackets in them.
This is what I am trying to achieve:

```
Title: "Song Name"
Artist: "DEF feat. ABC"
```

Basically is to drop everything in `Ost.` bracket and move the `feat.` bracket down to Artist field.

But the problem is, I need some is some code to detect the actual end of the main bracket (ignoring the sub-brackets) to format them properly.

Comment: Well asked question, add your attempts and it'll be perfect.

Comment: I'm not sure this can be done with regex.  You need to count brackets, and I don't believe regexes are [powerful enough](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages) to do that.

Comment: @Kevin Actually I don't mind if it's regex or not, I actually didn't even have an idea of how to do it. All I need is a python (even pseudo) code of basic idea to shed some light of how to achieve this.

Comment: If `(feat.` can only appear in the top nesting level, then easiest would be to just search for that using a regex because then nesting wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: As Python regexes do not support recursive pattern, I'd rather try [PLY](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/) for that. You can also find it on [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ply/3.1). It is more complex to write than simple regexes but far more powerful.

Comment: @interjay: We're looking for the closing bracket, not the opening.  But you could use a positive lookahead for `(Ost.`, assuming that never appears in nested brackets.

Answer (score 0):

So here is a new way to count bracket, i defined a function :

```
def getInsideBracket(title):
    bracket = 0
    last = 0
    first = 0
    for pos, car in  enumerate(title):
        if car == '(':
            if bracket == 0:
                first = pos
            bracket += 1

        elif car == ')':
            bracket -= 1
            if bracket == 0:
                last = pos
                return first, last
```

It get all in the feat bracket.
So now you can just take this two position (first and last) :

```
fist, last = getInsideBracket(title)
feat = title[first:last]
feat = feat[feat.index(' '):]
```

You have to add `feat` to your artist string and remove this block  from title string:

```
title = title[:title.index('(feat.')]
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't seem to work, when (feat. xyz(ab)) is fed through it just returns "feat. xyz". Basically it ends on the next non-word character which is not what I want. I want to achieve some thing like this: "feat. xyz(ab)"

Comment: I edited my answer it's ```m.group(1)``` to get only names. For your question about xyz(ab), I don't really see artists have '()' but whatever. Is this the only special case you need ?

Comment: I edited my answer. Of course this new answer works only if you have always title with the first bracket in (feat. .... ). Now  it works with ABC(XY).